# unable to open filp_open file in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, file, module, kernel

I'm building a Linux module in C. I have two folders *kernel_mode* and *user_mode*.

code in *user_mode.c*:

```
fd=open("/dev/iot-device", O_RDWR);
printf("call open() fd= %d \n\n",fd);
error("fd");
```

code in *kernel_mode.c*:

```
int iot_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
   file = filp_open("dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR, 0);
   printk(KERN_NOTICE "iot_open(): filp_open calls\n");
   if (IS_ERR(file) || file == NULL)
   {
       ret=PTR_ERR(file);
       printk(KERN_NOTICE "Cannot open destination file %s || ret=%d\n",path,ret);
       return ret;
   }
(...)
}
struct file_operations char_fops = 
{
    .owner =    THIS_MODULE,
    .open =     iot_open,(...)
}
```

**kernel_mode.c** I like this:

*make (I have a makefile)*

*insmod kernel_mode.ko*

**user_mode.c** I run like this:

*gcc user_mode.c -o user_mode*

*./user_mode*

terminal output:

```
call open() fd= -1 

fd: Permission denied
```

**dmesg**:

```
iot_open(): open() open function was called
iot_open(): filp_open calls
Cannot open destination file dev/ttyUSB0  ||  ret=-2
```

Permissions and access rights

```
crw-------   1 root root   (...) iot-device
crw-rw----   1 root dialout (...)  ttyUSB0
```

Used different flags in *open()* and *filp_open()*: **O_RDONLY** or **O_RDWR**

What am I missing? Please respond to my request! Any help is welcome

Comment: You specified relative path. If `filp_open()` is called from `module_init` context it tries to open file relatively to working directory of `insmod` process.

Comment: @dimich  when I call `insmod` then `module_init` from *kernel_mode.c* is actually called. but I'm calling *./user_mode* and there `open()` and this `open()` , from *user_mode*, calls `iot_open()` and there `filp_open()`

Comment: Again: path you specified to `filp_open()` is relative: `dev/...` instead of absolute path `/dev/...`. It is relative to working dir of process opened your `/dev/iot-device`. Anyway, opening device file inside of kernel module is bad idea, you'll encounter another problems even if fix this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inattention is to blame for everything.

1. `file = filp_open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDONLY, 0);`(did not have /dev)
2. permission must be `crw-rw---- iot-device`

you can do **chmod** every time.
But I added code to *kernel_mode.c*:

```
static int my_uevent(struct device *dev, struct kobj_uevent_env *env)
{
    add_uevent_var(env, "DEVMODE=%#o", 0660);
    printk(KERN_NOTICE "my_dev_uevent(): Permission is rw-rw---- 0660\n");
    return 0;
}
int init_module(void)
{[...]
    my_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);[...]
    my_class->dev_uevent = my_uevent;//this is a new code!

}
```